# Data not displaying correctly in CollectionView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview

I have trying to make a program that will display the image of crystals. After writing the code and formatting the StoryBoard, when I run the app the images are tiny and there are no labels displayed. I have constraints. [image: Screenshot of iPhone11]

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let imageArray = [UIImage(named: "1"),UIImage(named: "2"),UIImage(named: "3")]
    let nameArray = ["Rose Quartz", "Clear Quartz", "Clear Quartz 2"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.crystalPhotoImageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.crystalNameLabel.text! = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I have now unselected "Content View" in the Size Inspector of the cell and now everything is gigantic, lol. Still fiddling...

Comment: are you set size of collectionView cell in optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize

Comment: Changed "Estimate Size" to "None" in the Size Inspector of the UICollectionView and it fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement to confirm the class has UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and you need to implement this functionn

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return cellSize
}
```